# 2004 Nissan Frontier V6 2WD Radiator Fan Clutch Removal

Tags: nissan, radiator, frontier

How do I remove/install the radiator fan clutch from the top or the bottom of a 2004 Nissan Frontier V6 2WD?

Comment: My question is not how, but whether the removal/installation should be done from above the cooling fan or from below. Thanks.

Comment: Not adding this as an answer since I'm not absolutely sure, but pull off the splash guard on the bottom. The radiator shroud should have a panel that pops off the bottom that will give you access to the fan. Come to think of it, pulling off that panel should allow you to remove the entire shroud. Once that's done, it's a matter of removing the belt(s) and carefully removing the fan bolts (carefully because the radiator fins bend easily). If you remove the shroud, you can either work from the top or bottom. If you only remove that panel on it, then the bottom.